# Would seawater flow be affected by a magnet?

Tags: water, electromagnetic-induction, conductors

Let's suppose that there are two streams of sea water, flowing on a flat inclined surface. Both of the streams are distant, independent of each other and parallel to each other.

Now lets image I put a magnet in between the streams, such that it isn't in contact with either of them and is equidistant. Since seawater is slightly conductive, if I start to move the magnet parallel to the two streams, would the two water streams be affected in any way?

Comment: Related concepts: [electromagnetic pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_pump), [eddy currents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current)

Comment: I suspect the answer is "yes", "but not very much" and "you should do an experiment to find out"

Comment: If your magnetic source is extremely strong like a neutron star, yes. Those magnetic fields will rip electrons from your body. Otherwise, probably not noticeable, if even measurable with the strongest magnets we have on Earth. Certainly not measurable with any common or even uncommon magnet.

Comment: I believe a flowing electrolytic solution in the presence of a magnetic field will exhibit the Hall effect.

Comment: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00815047

Answer (score 4):

There will be weak diamagnetic and Lenz's Law effects, and a small Faraday voltage will be generated across the stream.  [Magnetic flow meters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_flow_meter) work by measuring this voltage.

The flow velocity might be slowed slightly by [Lenz's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law), but the conductivity of sea water is too low for this to be significant. No Lenz's law effect was detected in this video on ["Interaction of a Magnetic Field with Saltwater in a Lenz's Law Demonstration"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jx2RRrseVo0), even for salt concentrations much higher than in sea water.

Water is [diamagnetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamagnetism) and hence is repelled by a magnetic field, as shown in this video on ["Everything Is Magnetic! Moving Water With Magnets And Levitating Frogs"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mMDRqKmqVNs). The best way to see this effect might be to look at water flowing down a very gently sloped hydrophobic surface where [the coefficient of friction is extremely low](https://doi.org/10.1088/1742-6596/89/1/012012).

A well-known detectable effect is an induced voltage. Each ion with electric charge $q_i$ in water flowing with a velocity $\vec{v}$ in a magnetic field $\vec{B}$ feels a [Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force):
Positive and negative ions will be pushed towards opposite sides of the stream, building up in density until the resulting electric field $\vec{E}$ is sufficient to balance the magnetic force, i.e.
$$\vec{E}=-\vec{v}\times\vec{B}$$
This is similar to what happens with the [Hall effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect), except in this case both positive and negative ions are flowing in the same, not opposite, direction.  For a flow with width $w$, we expect a voltage
$$V\sim w v B$$
This won't be a huge voltage, e.g. $V\sim 0.2$ volts for $w\sim 10$ cm, $v\sim 1$ m/s, and $B\sim 2$ tesla.

This voltage is independent of the ion concentration in the water, as long as there are some ions. The surface charge density needed is $\sigma \sim \epsilon_0 v B$, so we expect an ion charge density $\rho\sim \epsilon_0 v B/w$ to be sufficient. For the above values,  $\rho\sim 10^{-10}\,\mathrm{C/m^3}$. Even distilled water has plenty of ions, with an $H^+$ density of $10^{-7}$ mol/L (i.e. [pH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PH)=$7$), which is about $10$ coulombs per cubic metre. (I believe  commercial magnetic flow meters don't work on distilled water because the [resistance across the fluid must be less than the meter's internal resistance](https://doi.org/10.1088/0143-0807/33/1/010).)

None of the above effects require the magnet to be moving. The Lenz's Law and induced voltage depend on the relative motion of the water ions and the magnetic field, while the diamagnetic repulsion depends on the gradient of the magnetic field intensity.

Answer (score 0):

Since the water is streaming, moving the magnet does not change the physical situation (unless you move it at the 'average speed of the water' and so we suppose you don't)

Now you have positive and negative Ions inside this water, which means essentially there is no net flux of charge. So the stream as a macroscopic object is not expected to change.

However, for each Ion inside, they may be affected by the Lorentz force. I do not understand why you need two streams?

Comment: The follow up question would have been, if there were any change in direction of flow, would it be the same deviation for both streams at either side of the magnet or opposite?

Comment: @DarioDenizErgün Depends on how the magnet is oriented.